# gtk3 Windows - Exe made by cx_freeze gives ValueError : Namespace Gtk not available

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, gtk3, cx-freeze, setup.py

I have an app built in Gtk3 Python3.4(Windows) which works fine on Pycharm but when I create an exe using cx_freeze , It gives the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "obfuscated.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\__init__.py", line 118, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
```

The imports I've done in my app are -

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Gio, GObject
import sqlite3
```

My setup.py file -

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
#import os
#os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\BRAHMDEV\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
#os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\BRAHMDEV\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tk8.6"
executables = [
    Executable("obfuscated.py",
               icon="evm_bg_KYa_icon.ico")
]

buildOptions = {"packages":["sqlite3", "gi"], "include_files":["mydatabase.db", "AgeSearch.png", "android.png", "candidate.jpg",
                                                               "CasteSearch.png", "duplicate.png", "FileStyle.css", "GenSearch.png", "Hof.png", "Placeholder.png", "voter slip.png"]}

setup(name="Voter Search Engine",
      version="2.1.3",
      description="Voter Search Engine Setup",
      options={"build_exe":buildOptions},
      executables=executables,
      )
```

And when I executed python setup.py build this was what took place -

https://pastebin.com/uutDJ8at

Comment: Looks like the python-gobject library is being pulled in but the GIR&typelib files it depends on are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I tried this on Pyinstaller as well got the same error , but found the solution 
[here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1966)